# How can I make interrupt() work?

Tags: java, multithreading

Could you have a look at the picture. Now the A step ago I executed this.interrupt(). You can see that this.isInterrupted() is false.  I was scrutinyzing - "this" has not changed. It had the same id (12). So, why there is no result of the interrupt() method?

[image]

Added later. Code as text:

```
@Override
protected void letUsFinalise() {
    this.interrupt();
}
```

Comment: Post code as text, not as picture.

Comment: Well, there is not much code to post. Just one method. If I have understood you correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc of `interrupted()` says:

> Tests whether the current thread has been interrupted. **The interrupted status of the thread is cleared by this method**. In other words, **if this method were to be called twice in succession, the second call would return false**

(emphasis mine)

BTW, `interrupted()` is a static method. It should be called on the Thread class, not in `this`. And given that it has a side-effect, you should create a watch in your debugger for it. Watch `isInterruped()` instead.

Comment: I can't cath the idea. I have not called interrupted() method. I called only interrupt(). Well, interrupted() was added as a new watch. But it can't affect, I would say.

Comment: How do you think the debugger is able to display the value returned by `interrupted()`, other than by calling the method? The debugger is what is calling `interrupted()` because you asked the debugger to watch the value returned by `interrupted()`.

Comment: Thank you for this. Valuable experience. Anyway, I removed this watch. And nothing has changed.

Comment: Then there is a problem with the code. Post an example reproducing the problem, and printing the value of `isInterrupted()`. Note that the javadoc of isInterrupted() says: *A thread interruption ignored because a thread was not alive at the time of the interrupt will be reflected by this method returning false.* This is probably what happens: you're interrupting a thread that is not alive.

Comment: Thank you. Your last comment seems to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that interrupt() may not stop the execution of the thread immediately.
Debugging a multithreaded program may not be as simple as that as the execution may be completely different. Therefore I suggest you to do the following:

```
while(!Thread.foo.isInterrupted()){
   //wait or  do something
   }
```